# Android - ellipsize="end" Not Showing Three Dots

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview

I'm working on a `TextView` which is contained in a `ConstraintLayout`.

I want ellipsize to add three dots at the end of text(in the TextView) if its length exceeds maxLength.

maxLines="1" and ellipsize="end" seemed to the best answer after a thorough research about my question. Unfortunately, it didn't work for my case. The three dots did't show at all.

Here's the snapshot :

[image]

The original string was "Test for long description"(The n was dropped). It's supposed to show "Test for long descrip...".

Here's my xml :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:maxLength="24"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="DescriptionView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72" />
```

I feel like there's something override ellipsize in the XML, or did I miss something crucial in the XML file?

Comment: You posted image is not for the xml file

Comment: @navylover The xml is for the description TextView in the image. The image is for the whole Constraintlayout.

Comment: improved formating and grammar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is:

```
android:maxLength="24"
```

remove it since you want the `TextView` to be ellipsized. 
A TextView gets ellipsized when it is not wide enough to show the whole text.  
 I think you do not understand what this attribute `android:ellipsize="end"` is all about. 
If it is wide enough then you will not see any dots at the end because they are not needed. 
If you set `android:layout_width="40dp"` then you will see the dots.  
With `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` the `TextView` is wide enough and it is not ellipsized.

Comment: Not working. The only change is it shows the entire string, but not ellipsized at all.

Comment: If it shows the whole string this means that it is wide enough to show the whole string.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Everything goes as what I want after setting the TextView width to a particular value!

Answer (score 4):

1) Add one more property `android:singleLine="true"` in your Textview

(But its Deprecated so use second option)

2) Use this three together

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: It's not working, even scrollHorizontally can't scroll, but thanks anyway.

Comment: have you set fixed width for EditText ?

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated,use `android:maxLines= "1" `  instead

Answer (score 1):

Ellipsize is quite a pain in android, apply below on your textView :

`txtDescription.setSingleLine(true);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: No , it's not working. It's still the same, but thanks anyway.

Comment: play with layout width, try giving particular value.

Comment: YES! It works. It's finally ellipsized! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The key for making three dots shows is constrain the width of the text view.
Suppose the name of image in your posted figure is `left_image`,
change the xml attributes of TextView as below:

```
....
android:layout_width="0dp" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_image"
....
```

above two lines make the width of TextView is constrainted(between left img and right border of parent).

Comment: I set the TextView width to a particular value, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case following line was the problem. I commented it out and it worked.

```
<item name="android:inputType">text|textNoSuggestions</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to use a fixed width for the textview instead of `maxLength` attribute in your xml
In xml :

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

And in java/kotlin program :[Important]

```
textDescription.setSelected(true) -> Java
```

or

```
textDescription.isSelected=true -> Kotlin
```