# Can you use ellipsize with maxLength in xml?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, ellipsize

So I’m trying to have an ellipsize at the end of a `TextView` if the text length exceeds 30 characters.
I tried to achieve this in xml using `maxLength`, `maxEms`, `ellipsize = end`, `maxLines` ... But it doesn’t seem to work.
Can this be achieved in xml or it has to be hardcoded ? If so, how can this be done ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textview - Max Length not working with ellipsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933621/textview-max-length-not-working-with-ellipsize)

Comment: Not really, the solution seems to work for `android:maxLines = 1` ( Even tho I found weird behaviour with `maxLines = 1` ) and I want to achieve this on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer because I can't yet add this as comment. I think this may answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53349554/13520662

Comment: Not really. Because I’m not using `maxLength` at all here but it’s rather `maxEms`.
@cutiko Answer was good but as I said, it only works with one single line.
I think my use case can only be done with written code and not xml.